# This merchant is not enabled for Google Pay on Test environment

Tags: android, google-pay

I'm trying to implement a payment request for google pay natively on Android for a custom merchant and I'm receiving this error:

`This merchant is not enabled for Google Pay`.

When I tried to resolve what exception is thrown I found this:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown.
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:3)
at com.google.android.gms.wallet.AutoResolveHelper.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@18.0.0:18)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zzy.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@18.0.0:4)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zzt.dispatchTransaction(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@18.0.0:63)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.wallet.zza.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet@@18.0.0:13)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

And my request looks like this:

```
{
   "apiVersion":2,
   "apiVersionMinor":0,
   "allowedPaymentMethods":[
      {
         "type":"CARD",
         "parameters":{
            "allowedAuthMethods":[
               "PAN_ONLY",
               "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
            ],
            "allowedCardNetworks":[
               "AMEX",
               "MASTERCARD",
               "VISA"
            ]
         },
         "tokenizationSpecification":{
            "type":"PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
            "parameters":{
               "gateway":"gateway",
               "gatewayMerchantId":"124185"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "transactionInfo":{
      "currencyCode":"PLN",
      "totalPriceStatus":"FINAL",
      "totalPrice":"2.00"
   },
   "merchantInfo":{
      "merchantId":"9876143410",
      "merchantName":"Test Merchant",
      "merchantOrigin":"localhost"
   }
}
```

The issue is that I'm using a TEST environment so I don't see why this message should be shown at all.

Comment: Is this message showing in red color with the gmail id in the phone? If yes the you have add a real card to your gmail and the retry the payment.

Comment: No it's not....

Comment: Did you tried with adding real card to gmail account?

Comment: I have added real card to gmail account. It's not related to the client side.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk hi, did you manage to solve that? I found this today too, no docs and your question is the one thing, that could be found about this error

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk try to remove filters in logs and find something related to wallet, I had wrong tokenizationSpecification

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to make an agreement with Google to get enabled.
My gues is you might not progress with testing as well if you don't proceed with agreent (which may unlock testing opportunities).

Logically they don't have entries of your testing organisation / PSP provider, so they won't know how to process the given data. For this reason google has testing PSP ready.

If you want to get confirmed as PSP by google, i bet you have to sign up with them and then you might get all the needed info for implementing services between google and your organisation.

Try following the link:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors

find the "Participating processors" paragraph and choose to "fill out an onboarding request" in the PSP section.

After moving through the process you might get more clues on what has to be done.

Comment: This shouldn't be required for test integration.

Comment: i assume a legal merchant is indeed required. because those merchants provide their own environment for testing.

and based on google examples it has to be one from the list.

even in testing envoronment google pay api connects to merchant before generating a token. so it has to be legal one, otherwise google wont know how to handle the data even for testing. 

when i'm in testing environment i see googles requests before it returns me token.

Comment: No, merchant can be anything in the test environment for Google Pay. Have a look at the demos: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos#basic-example. Works with `{ merchantName: 'Example Merchant' }`. Google Pay doesn't provides a mocked response when testing.

Comment: then it has to have specific json parameters:type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }