# 6: BuyFlow UI needs to be shown

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play, google-pay

There is a problem when i am click on payWithGoogle Button
I am implementing Google Pay in my Android Application and when i click on button then following error is getting after debugging code (PFA Screenshot[image: Getting Error From Google])

And sending Following request (PFA IMAge 2[image: Sending Request to Google Client])

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Buyflow UI needs to be shown ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155390/this-merchant-is-not-enabled-for-google-pay-on-test-environment)

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a test integration with the environment set to `TEST`?

Comment: @Soc this is the test Environment

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are doing something like:

**Kotlin:**

```
paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(...).apply {
    addOnCompleteListener { t ->
            Log.d(TAG, "${t.result}")
        }
}
```

**Java:**

```
Task<PaymentData> task = paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(...)
task.addOnCompleteListener(t -> {
    Log.d(TAG, t.result.toString())
})
```

The problem is that you can't take ***t.result*** in listener. You can only get ***paymentData*** when the ***onActivityResult*** event is triggered.