# Google Pay "BuyFlow UI needs to be shown"

Tags: android, payment-gateway, google-pay

So I am developing an application which has Google Pay integrated into it, using the starter template code on the documentation[here](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart/blob/master/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/activity/CheckoutActivity.kt). However, I get the error message "BuyFlow UI needs to be shown" in both test mode and production environment, with the exception that the Payment sheet still gets displayed in test mode.

I then found this stack-overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67320124/10359739) which said to get the payment result in onActivityResult. I then refactored my code to use the one provided [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#checkoutactivity.kt-kotlin). However, I still get the typical OR-BIBED 07 error message and no error message. Any help would be appreciated .

This is the code that gets executed on click of the googlePayBtn, which gives the "BuyFlow UI error"

```
private fun requestPayment(){
        googlePayBtn.isClickable = false
        val priceInCents = 1L

//        val paymentDataRequestJson = paymentsUtil.getPaymentDataRequest(priceInCents)
//        val request = PaymentDataRequest.fromJson(paymentDataRequestJson.toString())
//
//        AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(
//            paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request), requireActivity(), LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE)

        val task = getLoadPaymentDataTask(priceInCents)

        task.addOnCompleteListener { completedTask ->
            if (completedTask.isSuccessful) {
                completedTask.result.let(::handlePaymentSuccess)
            }
            else {
                when (val exception = completedTask.exception) {
                    is ResolvableApiException -> {
                        handleError(exception.statusCode, exception.message)
                        resolvePaymentForResult.launch(
                            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.resolution).build()
                        )
                        handleError(exception.statusCode, exception.message)
                    }

                    is ApiException -> {
                        handleError(exception.statusCode, exception.message)
                    }

                    else -> {
                        handleError(
                            CommonStatusCodes.INTERNAL_ERROR, "Unexpected non API" +
                                    " exception when trying to deliver the task result to an activity!"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        googlePayBtn.isClickable = true

    }
```

This is the modified code which does not show an error message but still shows the OR_BIBED-07 dialog.

```
private fun requestPayment(){
        googlePayBtn.isClickable = false
        val priceInCents = 1L

        val paymentDataRequestJson = paymentsUtil.getPaymentDataRequest(priceInCents)
        val request = PaymentDataRequest.fromJson(paymentDataRequestJson.toString())

        AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(
            paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request), requireActivity(), LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode){

            LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE ->{
                when (resultCode) {
                    RESULT_OK ->{

                        data?.let { intent ->
                            PaymentData.getFromIntent(intent)?.let(::handlePaymentSuccess)
                        }
                    }

                    RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                        // The user cancelled the payment attempt
                    }

                    AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR -> {

                        AutoResolveHelper.getStatusFromIntent(data)?.let {
                            handleError(it.statusCode, it.statusMessage)
                        }
                    }
                }

                googlePayBtn.isClickable = true
            }
        }
    }
```